# Slider width control on (Thunderbird on) Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: themes, thunderbird, gtk

Which file(s) do I edit in order to widen scrollbars in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 17.10?

gtk-widgets.css in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0 has promising lines
gtk-widgets.css in "/gtk-3.20 must pull the info from another file(s)? The file refers to "-GtkRange-sliderwidth", but I cannot ID the source.

Is gtk-3.20 used or is gtk-3.0 used?

Thanks,
Tim